Trouble in finding Similarity Solutions
This question is an exercise problem from J. D. Logan's book "An Introduction to Non-Linear Partial Differential Equations" (Page 233).
Use the similarity method to find an analytical solution to the problem $$xu_t-u_{xx} = 0 \ \ x>0,\, t>0$$
$$u(x,0) = 0, \forall x>0$$
$$u(\infty,t)=0, \forall t>0$$
$$u_x(0,t)=-1, \forall t>0$$
My attempt:
A self-similar solution is obtained as $$u(x,t) = t^c y\left( \frac{x}{t^{1/3}}\right),$$ by checking the invariance of the given PDE under a stretching transform.
Now, the job is to find constant $c$ and the function $y(z)$. I have plugged in back to the given PDE to get the ODE:
$$y''+\frac{z^2}{3}y'-zc y =0.$$
Given conditions on $u(x,t)$ can be expressed in terms of $y$ as $y(\infty)=0$ and $y'(0)=-1$ and $c=1/3$.
This gives the ODE:
$$y''+\frac{z^2}{3}y'-\frac{z}{3}y=0$$
I'm unable to proceed further from here. How do I solve the obtained ODE which satisfies the above conditions?
